# xTrying to include a header block in Sympfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I am totally new to this. I took as an example the body block.

This is my base.html.twig file content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block header %} {% endblock %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my header from app\Resources\views\header\header.html.twig content:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block header %}
Header HeaderHeaderHeaderHeader
{% endblock %}
```

But this is not working for some reason. Do i need to do smth more ? thx

**[UPDATE]**

I attached an image to see what i want to achieve: [image]

This is folder structure:
[image]

[UPDATE]

The content of the index.html.twig file is:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
          afdsfsdfsfasddf
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
<style>
    body { background: #F5F5F5; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What template do you render in your controller?

Comment: If you trying to include template, use `include` Twig function: 
`{% include 'header/header.html.twig' %}`.

Comment: Try this : `{% extends ':base.html.twig' %}`

Comment: @adashbob I tried and doesn't work

Comment: @Martin  default/index.html.twig this template

Comment: Would you post content of `default/index.html.twig` please ? Only section where you extends `base.html.twig` and where you include or extends `header` file

Comment: @adashbob I did, please check it . thx :)

Comment: look at my anwser. The header have not extend  `base.html.twig`. You have to include it in `base.html.twig`

Answer (score 0):

you should inspire you in this example :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do that:

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {# header section #}
        <div>
             {% include ':header:header.html.twig' %}
             {% block header %} {% endblock %}
        </div>            

        {# body section #}
        <div>
             {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>

        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

**header.html.twig**

Remove this section

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block header %}
Header HeaderHeaderHeaderHeader
{% endblock %}
```

And make only the header content

**index.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
          afdsfsdfsfasddf
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
<style>
    body { background: #F5F5F5; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```